# How to include AdMob in a Titanium Android app?

Tags: android, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile, r.java-file

This would be my first time working with AdSense, previously I've used the `createAdView` for iOS, which is extremely simple to use. When I wanted to find the equivalent for AdSense I found Titanium doesn't offer functions to do so.

From what I've found, an [AdMob SDK module](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_modules/tree/master/admob/mobile/android/dist) is out for Titanium but when I put the line `<tool-api-level>14</tool-ai-level>`into my manifest file, I get the error message `Error Generating R.java from manifest`.

This is how my manifest looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.nenvo.desktop" android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <!-- TI_MANIFEST -->

    <application android:icon="@drawable/appicon"
        android:label="Desktop Lite" android:name="DesktopLiteApplication"
        android:debuggable="false">

        <!-- TI_APPLICATION -->

        <activity android:name=".DesktopLiteActivity"
            android:label="Desktop Lite" 
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Titanium"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="content" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <!-- <data android:scheme="file" /> -->
                <data android:mimeType="application/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
                <!-- <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.asd" /> -->
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>



        <activity android:name="org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
        <activity android:name="org.appcelerator.titanium.TiTranslucentActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
        <activity android:name="org.appcelerator.titanium.TiModalActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
        <activity android:name="ti.modules.titanium.ui.TiTabActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
        <activity android:name="ti.modules.titanium.ui.android.TiPreferencesActivity" />

        <service android:name="org.appcelerator.titanium.analytics.TiAnalyticsService"
            android:exported="false" />


    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
        <tool-api-level>14</tool-ai-level>
</manifest>
```

As far as I know if I set the `minSdkVersion` property to 8 it should run on earlier Android versions, but even on devices with Android 4.0 it doesn't compile.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought that the `<tool-api-level>14</tool-ai-level>` line was supposed to be inside my `custom Android manifest` since it was declared inside the `<android>`tag in my `tiapp.xml`. This thought of mine was wrong, it must be added inside the `tiapp.xml` like this:

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <tool-api-level>14</tool-api-level>
</android>
```

With this it worked just fine.